# How to detect whether the ios app is pirated or not?

Tags: iphone, ios, itunes

This is my first question here and iOS is something very new for me currently.
If we have an app on iTunes and same app on some third party appstore, then does it mean the app is pirated ?

How to detect if an app on Third Party Store is pirated version of the original app from iTunes ?
Any help is highly appreciable.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what third party store ?

Comment: There are no official 3rd party App Stores for iOS. If you didn't get it from Apple, it's probably pirated; & can only be installed on a jailbroken device.

Comment: Buscar : I am talking about any app stores. There are many. To name some : appchina, kuiayong, etc.

Comment: Tetsujin : Yes, there is a point in your comment. I guessed the same. But is there any way I can prove with stronger point. Say for example I can say "The certificate does not match so the app is pirated version of original app" or anything similar ???

Comment: @Tetsujin Not quite correct: "Chinese app store offers pirated iOS apps without the need to jailbreak"...http://www.extremetech.com/mobile/153849-chinese-app-store-offers-pirated-ios-apps-without-the-need-to-jailbreak

Comment: @Buscar웃SD - ouch, that's nasty! v1h5 that's outside my knowledge-base, sorry

Comment: @Tetsujin : That's ok. I really appreciate your attitude to help. Thank you. :) 
I think I am near the answer. Once cleared, I will update here. 
Thanks guys.

Comment: Are you asking from the point of view of a user ("how can I as a user find out whether this app I'm using is pirated") or as a developer ("how can my app determine whether it got pirated when running")?

Answer (score -1):

You can only install apps from itunes/the build in app-store.
Some apps are/claim to be installable through safari, but I wouldn't trust that.
If you have jailbroken your phone and installed an alternative app store, that is probably illegal, and will void your warranty (because apple won't let you jailbreak).
So if you have found a third party app store, it is probably fake, or illegal.

Comment: jailbreaking is not illegal

Comment: http://www.cultofmac.com/213144/unlocking-a-new-iphone-is-now-illegal-but-jailbreaking-is-still-safe-what-it-all-means-for-you/

Comment: Jailbreaking isn't illegal, installing a 3rd party app store which lets you download paid apps for free is technically not illegal, but installing those apps is.

Comment: Well jailbreaking your iPad is illegal it seems..